# GUI for JournalCTL

Tags: user-interface, systemd-journald

Is there any application/saas solution with a GUI to read/manage and filter logs from journalctl?

I am open for a native solution (osx preferred) as well for something running in the browser.

Comment: I suspect this question is more appropriate for Serverfault.com, but one could argue journalctl is "a tool primary used by developers" so I did not vote to close it.

Answer (score 0):

There is [QJournalCTL](https://github.com/pentix/qjournalctl), you can get the OSX build through Homebrew.